# QDialog return value, Accepted or Rejected only?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, c++14, qdialog

How to return custom value from a `QDialog`? It's [documented](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdialog.html#return-value-modal-dialogs) it returns

```
QDialog::Accepted   1
QDialog::Rejected   0
```

respectively if user press `Ok` of `Cancel`.

I'm thinking in a custom dialog presenting i.e. three check boxes to allow user to select some options. Would `QDialog` be appropriate for this?

Answer (score 6):

You'll be interested in 2 functions:

- `QDialog::setResult()` lets you use any integer as a return value (without closing the dialog): http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdialog.html#setResult.
- `QDialog::done()` does the same, except that it closes the dialog and makes `QDialog::exec()` return the result you specified: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdialog.html#done

Usually, the "OK" button in a QDialog is connected to the `QDialog::accept()` slot. You want to avoid this. Instead, write your own handler to set the return value:

```
// Custom dialog's constructor
MyDialog::MyDialog(QWidget *parent = nullptr) : QDialog(parent)
{
    // Initialize member variable widgets
    m_okButton = new QPushButton("OK", this);
    m_checkBox1 = new QCheckBox("Option 1", this);
    m_checkBox2 = new QCheckBox("Option 2", this);
    m_checkBox3 = new QCheckBox("Option 3", this);

    // Connect your "OK" button to your custom signal handler
    connect(m_okButton, &QPushButton::clicked, [=]
    {
        int result = 0;
        if (m_checkBox1->isChecked()) {
            // Update result
        }

        // Test other checkboxes and update the result accordingly
        // ...

        // The following line closes the dialog and sets its return value
        this->done(result);            
    });

    // ...
}
```

Comment: While this is possible, i'd usually just make the checkbox values accessible via getters and call them when exec() returns Accepted. That results in less code and tends to be more readable, too.

Comment: @JKSH, I was thinking in how to encode a combination of check boxes selection in an integer. But following Frank Osterfeld idea seems to help avoid that endeavor, which might  be a good thing.

Comment: Side question, `QWidget *parent = nullptr` is the current `Qt` recommended approach or is it a current C++ (C++14?) trend (I usually do/see `QWidget *parent = 0`) ?

Comment: Agreed, @FrankOsterfeld's approach is cleaner.

Comment: @KcFnMi `parent = 0` is the old style. C++11 introduced `nullptr`, so now it's better to write `parent = nullptr`.